# mathrm changes everything

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I am trying to make the differentiation mark in integrals (d) not italic. Example:

```
\documentstyle[html]{article}  
\title{QED}
\author{Ali}     
\date{September 8, 2013}
\begin{document}           
\maketitle              

\section{Q1}  
Test
       \[ \int 2x \mathrm{d}x = x^{2} \] 
\end{document}
```

This makes ALL the letters that appear after mathrm non italic. But I only want the "d" to be non italic, not everything. Any idea?

Comment: You are using an _ancient_ set up, as `\documentstyle` was part of LaTeX2.09, replaced by LaTeX2e in 1994. Certainly in my TeX Live 2013 the `html` style is not available.  What happens if you replace `\documentstyle` with `\documentclass`?

Comment: @JosephWright, That's it, perfect!

Yes, I was using a template which seems to be from 1986!

Comment: Also, consider define a macro `\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}` if you plan to use the differential multiple times across the document.

Answer (score 8):

You are using an ancient set up, as `\documentstyle` was part of LaTeX2.09, replaced by LaTeX2e in 1994. This is really *not* a good idea. Replace `\documentstyle` with `\documentclass` and all should be fine

```
\documentclass{article}  
\title{QED}
\author{Ali}     
\date{September 8, 2013}
\begin{document}           
\maketitle              

\section{Q1}  
Test
       \[ \int 2x \mathrm{d}x = x^{2} \] 
\end{document}
```